# IdentityServer3 DiscoveryDocument fails to load

Tags: automapper, identityserver3

I have an IdentityServer3 server setup and it's configured to use Entity Framework for getting client and scope information from the database.

When I add a new scope to the database (dbo.Scopes) if ShowInDiscoveryDocument = 0 then all is well and the well-known document loads correctly. However, if ShowInDiscoveryDocument = 1 then I get the following error:

```
Message: "An error has occurred.",
ExceptionMessage: "The type initializer for 'IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.EntitiesMap' threw an exception.",
ExceptionType: "System.TypeInitializationException",
StackTrace: " at IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.EntitiesMap.ToModel(Scope s) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection) at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpointController.d__11.MoveNext() in 
c:\local\identity\server3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Endpoints\Connect\DiscoveryEndpointController.cs:line 89 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Threading.Tasks.System.Web.Http908956.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext() in c:\local\identity\server3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Validation\ScopeValidator.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\local\identity\server3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Validation\ScopeValidator.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() in c:\local\identity\server3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Validation\ScopeValidator.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\local\identity\server3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Validation\ScopeValidator.cs:line 0",
    InnerException: {
    Message: "An error has occurred.",
    ExceptionMessage: "Could not load type 'AutoMapper.IMapperConfiguration' from assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=5.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005'.",
    ExceptionType: "System.TypeLoadException",
    StackTrace: " at IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.EntitiesMap..cctor()"
```

Comment: Did you update to a newer version of automapper than the one used by IdSvr.EF?

Comment: I tried using version 5.0.0 which is what I thought Idsvr used. That didn't work. I also tried 5.0.2

Comment: Why not just use the one that's it built against? IOW, don't update the nuget. There's an open issue for this on the issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you. I downgraded AutoMapper to 4.2.1 and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has been reported and I think fixed in the sources, I do not know if the nugget package has the fix yet.

Comment: Not yet. And I need to fill this dialog box with more characters so the hostile SO police will let me post... *sigh*

Comment: 2.5.1 NuGet is now released.